# This jquery plugin detects the $window scroll position, how do I tell this plugin to use an element's scroll position instead?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a jQuery plugin called [hcsticky](http://someweblog.com/hcsticky-jquery-floating-sticky-plugin/) it detects a window's scroll position and then applies a `position:fixed` to an element.

My problem is that I have an `position:absolute` container that scrolls *instead of the window*. This means that my plugin doesn't apply the fixed position to my element.

This only happens on tablets as larger dimensions use a different stylesheet and the window itself scrolls.

Right now I have the plugin setup like this:

```
$('#imageContent').hcSticky({
    innerSticker: $('#textContent'),
    stickTo: $('#textContent'),
    bottomEnd: -60,
    top: 60
});
```

Right now this detects whether the `scrollTop` has has reached the top of `#textContent` and will apply fixed to `#imageContent` for the height of `#textContent`. None of this is triggered because, I believe, the function is measuring the `$window` `scrollTop` and not the `#scroller` `scrollTop`.

Am I missing something, is there something in this plugin's options that enables this that I'm missing? [here](http://someweblog.com/hcsticky-jquery-floating-sticky-plugin/)

Comment: if you cannot find anything in the documentation then edit the plugin's file to accommodate the use of an element instead of window.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Yea, I guess, I assumed this feature would be part of the plugin as it's quite a common thing to do, especially with mobile. I just thought I might have missed something obvious so checked on here.